# Imprimir resultado de búsqueda en fpdf

Tags: fpdf

buenas tardes comunidad.
Mi problema es el siguiente.
Lo que pasa es que he estado trabajando con fpdf en la impresión de unos horarios por fecha, ahora les anexo el código. en el cuál sí imprime de manera correcta, pero lo que quiero es que ahora sólo imprima por nombre del profesor.

La variable dato, la tengo en un archivo .js

```
<?php 
 $dato = $_GET['dato']; 

// para imprimir con la fecha hago el siguiente if

if(strlen($_GET['desde'])>0 and strlen($_GET['hasta'])>0){
$desde = $_GET['desde'];
$hasta = $_GET['hasta'];

$verDesde = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($desde));
$verHasta = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($hasta));

}else{
$desde = '1111-01-01';
$hasta = '9999-12-30';

$verDesde = '__/__/____';
$verHasta = '__/__/____';
}

 ob_start();
 require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
 require('conexion.php');
 $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');

 $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
 $pdf->Cell(77, 8, 'Nombre Profesor', 0);
 $pdf->Cell(65, 8, 'Materia', 0);
 $pdf->Cell(20, 8, 'Fecha', 0);
 $pdf->Cell(18, 8, 'Grupo', 0);
 $pdf->Cell(18, 8, 'Horario', 0);
```

Ahora la consulta en mysql

```
// para imprimir con fecha hago este query
$productos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_salaa WHERE fecha BETWEEN 
'$desde' AND '$hasta' ");

// pero quiero que me imprima con el nombre de profesor.
$productos1 = mysql_query("SELECT nombrePro,nombreMate,fecha,grupo,horario 
FROM tbl_salaa WHERE nombrePro LIKE '%$dato%'");

$registro = 0;
if(mysql_num_rows($productos1)>0){
  while($productos2 = mysql_fetch_array(**$productos1**)){

   $registro = $registro+1;

   $pdf->Cell(77, 8,$productos2['nombrePro'], 0);
   $pdf->Cell(65, 8, $productos2['nombreMate'], 0);
   $pdf->Cell(20, 8, date('d/m/Y', strtotime($productos2['fecha'])), 0);
   $pdf->Cell(18, 8, $productos2['grupo'], 0);
   $pdf->Cell(18, 8, $productos2['horario'], 0);    
   $pdf->Ln(8);
    }
   }
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
   $pdf->Cell(104,8,'',0);

   $pdf->Output('reporte.pdf','D');
 ?>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano. 
Es la primera vez que trabajo con fpdf. ^^ 
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error o por qué no puedes imprimir los registros con el nombre del profesor? En tu formulario (o donde recibas el parámetro del nombre del profesor) crea un campo que te permita introducir el nombre del profesor. Ya que lo hayas enviado, lo pasas en tu consulta.